# Generic term for hbm2ddl.auto (entity classes to DDL) capability

Tags: hibernate, domain-driven-design, hbm2ddl, model-driven-development

I would like to know what the **generic term** is for hibernate's Entity classes to DDL (**hbm2ddl**) capability.

Is it ***Domain Driven Design*** or ***Model Driven Development*** or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it certainly is not Domain-Driven Design. hbm2ddl can be used in conjunction with DDD but doesn't have much to do with DDD principles. DDD is less focused on the persistence technology and more focused on the business domain.

MDD can be an arguable point. One could say this is part of MDD because the MDD idea is to use modeling artifacts in the code. Using domain model classes to generate the database schema can be seen as an example of MDD.